# Too heavy a lens?

Tags: lens, dslr, repair

Silly question. I have a Nikon D5100, that unfortunately just needed to go in for service. I am trying to make sure I don't do whatever I did again. I just got a new 500mm lens, it is quite heavy. Is it possible to damage the camera with a lens that is too heavy for it?

Answer (score 5):

As a rule of thumb, if the lens comes with a tripod ring, you hold the lens with a camera attached rather than the typical holding the camera with the lens attached. If you have a heavy lens and try to hold it up with the camera it *could* put extra stress on the mount.

Comment: It is possible to damage the camera if the lens has mechanical interference with some of the moving parts (e.g. the mirror), or if the lens mount is not quite compatible. Just the static weight of a 500 mm lens probably would not damage the camera (though shaking the camera amplifies force by the lever arm of the long lens).